# SQL Server stored procedure complication

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to call `uspCalculateTaxes` procedure inside of `uspGetGrossPay` and I'm not understanding how to use the parameters. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USE dbSQL1;     -- Get out of the master database
SET NOCOUNT ON; -- Report only errors

-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Drop Tables
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TSalaries' )                     IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE  TSalaries
IF OBJECT_ID( 'THours' )                        IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE  THours
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TPayrolls' )                     IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE  TPayrolls
IF OBJECT_ID( 'THourlyPayRate' )                IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE  THourlyPayRate
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TTaxRates' )                     IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE  TTaxRates
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TEmployees' )                    IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE  TEmployees
IF OBJECT_ID( 'TPayrollStatuses' )              IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE  TPayrollStatuses



-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Drop Procedures
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID( 'uspGetGrossPay')                 IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE uspGetGrossPay
IF OBJECT_ID( 'uspCalculateSalary')             IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE uspCalculateSalary
IF OBJECT_ID( 'uspCalculateGrossPay')           IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE uspCalculateGrossPay
IF OBJECT_ID( 'uspCalculateTaxes')          IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE uspCalculateTaxes



-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step #1: Create Tables
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE TEmployees
(
     intEmployeeID          INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intPayrollStatusID     INTEGER         NOT NULL        --hourly or salary
    ,strEmployeeID          VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL        --actual employee ID
    ,strFirstName           VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strLastName            VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strAddress             VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strCity                VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strState               VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,strZip                 VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TEmployees_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intEmployeeID )

)

CREATE TABLE TPayrollStatuses
(
     intPayrollStatusID     INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,strStatus              VARCHAR(1)      NOT NULL        --S for salary and H for hourly are only values allowed
    ,strDescription         VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TPayrollStatuses_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intPayrollStatusID    )
    ,CONSTRAINT CK_PayrollStatus CHECK ( strStatus = 'H' OR strStatus = 'S')        -- ********CHECK CONSTRAINT ******keeps input to S or H only
)


CREATE TABLE THourlyPayRate
(
     intEmployeeRateID      INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intEmployeeID          INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,monRate                MONEY           NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT THourlyPayRate_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intEmployeeRateID )
    ,CONSTRAINT UQ_EmployeeID UNIQUE( intEmployeeID  )  -- EMPLOYEES SHOULD ONLY HAVE 1 HOURLY RATE
)

CREATE TABLE TSalaries
(
     intSalaryID            INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intEmployeeID          INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,monSalary              MONEY           NOT NULL
    ,intFrequency           INTEGER         NOT NULL  -- frequency of pay periods # per year for our purpose 52 but could change
    ,CONSTRAINT TSalaries_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intSalaryID )
    ,CONSTRAINT UQ_intEmployeeID UNIQUE( intEmployeeID  )  -- EMPLOYEES SHOULD ONLY HAVE 1 SALARY

)

CREATE TABLE THours
(
     intHourID              INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intEmployeeID          INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,dtmEndDate             DATETIME        NOT NULL    -- date pay period ends
    ,decHours               DECIMAL(6, 2)   NOT NULL    -- HOURS WORKED THIS PERIOD (6, 2) is referred to as the precision and scale of the decimal
    ,CONSTRAINT THours_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intHourID )     -- precision is the total digits and scale is the # of digits to the right of the decimal
                                                        -- in this case we have 6 total with 2 right of the decimal 1962.53 is how it would look
)

CREATE TABLE TTaxRates
(
     intTaxRateID           INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,intEmployeeID          INTEGER         NOT NULL
    ,decStateRate           DECIMAL(6, 2)           NOT NULL  -- State income tax rate
    ,decLocalRate           DECIMAL(6, 2)           NOT NULL  -- Local income tax rate
    ,CONSTRAINT TTaxRates_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intTaxRateID )

)

CREATE TABLE TPayrolls
(
     intPayrollID           INTEGER IDENTITY    NOT NULL
    ,intEmployeeID          INTEGER             NOT NULL
    ,monGrossPay            MONEY               NOT NULL
    ,monFederalTax          MONEY               NOT NULL
    ,monStateTax            MONEY               NOT NULL
    ,monLocalTax            MONEY               NOT NULL
    ,dtmCurrentDate         DATETIME            NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT TPayrolls_PK PRIMARY KEY ( intPayrollID )
)

-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step #2: Identify and Create Foreign Keys
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- #    Child                               Parent                      Column(s)
-- -    -----                               ------                      ---------
-- 1    TEmployees                          TPayrollStatuses            intPayrollStatusID
-- 2    THourlyPayRate                      TEmployees                  intEmployeeID
-- 3    TSalaries                           TEmployees                  intEmployeeID
-- 4    THours                              TEmployees                  intEmployeeID
-- 5    TTaxRates                           TEmployees                  intEmployeeID


-- 1
ALTER TABLE TEmployees ADD CONSTRAINT TEmployees_TPayrollStatuses_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intPayrollStatusID ) REFERENCES TPayrollStatuses ( intPayrollStatusID )

-- 2
ALTER TABLE THourlyPayRate ADD CONSTRAINT THourlyPayRate_TEmployees_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intEmployeeID ) REFERENCES TEmployees ( intEmployeeID )

-- 3
ALTER TABLE TSalaries ADD CONSTRAINT TSalaries_TEmployees_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intEmployeeID ) REFERENCES TEmployees ( intEmployeeID )

-- 4
ALTER TABLE THours ADD CONSTRAINT THours_TEmployees_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intEmployeeID ) REFERENCES TEmployees ( intEmployeeID )

-- 5
ALTER TABLE TTaxRates ADD CONSTRAINT TTaxRates_TEmployees_FK
FOREIGN KEY ( intEmployeeID ) REFERENCES TEmployees ( intEmployeeID )

-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step #3: Add data
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO TPayrollStatuses ( intPayrollStatusID, strStatus, strDescription )
VALUES   ( 1, 'S', 'Salary' )
        ,( 2, 'H', 'Hourly')

INSERT INTO TEmployees ( intEmployeeID, intPayrollStatusID, strEmployeeID, strFirstName, strLastName, strAddress, strCity, strState, strZip )
VALUES   ( 1, 1, 'AC1524', 'James', 'Allen', '1979 Park Place', 'Cincinnati', 'Oh', '45208' )
        ,( 2, 2, 'MN0195', 'Sally', 'Frye', '196 Main St.', 'Milford', 'Oh', '45232' )
        ,( 3, 1, 'HR5243', 'Fred', 'Mening', '19 Ft Wayne Ave.', 'West Chester', 'Oh', '45069' )
        ,( 4, 2, 'MN0645', 'Bill', 'Leford', '174 Chance Ave', 'Cold Spring', 'Ky', '44038' )
        ,( 5, 2, 'SH0326', 'Susan', 'Maelle', '109 Forrest St.', 'Lawrenceburg', 'In', '43098' )
        ,( 6, 1, 'EX26410', 'John', 'Snowden', '1709 ALes Lane', 'Milan', 'In', '43168' )


INSERT INTO THourlyPayRate ( intEmployeeRateID, intEmployeeID, monRate )
VALUES   ( 1, 2, 10.00 )
        ,( 2, 4, 11.86 )
        ,( 3, 5, 10.00 )

INSERT INTO TSalaries ( intSalaryID, intEmployeeID, monSalary, intFrequency )
VALUES   ( 1, 1, 90000.00, 52 )
        ,( 2, 3, 45597.29, 52 )
        ,( 3, 6, 255597.29, 52 )

INSERT INTO THours ( intHourID, intEmployeeID, dtmEndDate, decHours )
VALUES   ( 1, 2, '1/19/2018', 46.25 )
        ,( 2, 4, '1/19/2018', 42.55 )
        ,( 3, 5, '1/19/2018', 38.00 )
        ,( 4, 2, '1/26/2018', 40.00 )
        ,( 5, 1, '1/26/2018', 49.89 )
        ,( 6, 2, '1/26/2018', 30.00 )
        ,( 7, 3, '1/26/2018', 49.89 )
        ,( 8, 4, '1/26/2018', 51.23 )
        ,( 9, 5, '1/26/2018', 50.00 )
        ,( 10, 6, '1/26/2018', 51.23 )

INSERT INTO TTaxRates ( intTaxRateID, intEmployeeID, decStateRate, decLocalRate )
VALUES   ( 1, 1, .0495, .021 )
        ,( 2, 2, .0495, .021 )
        ,( 3, 3, .0495, .021 )
        ,( 4, 4, .055, .021 )
        ,( 5, 5, .0323, .021 )
        ,( 6, 6, .0323, .021 )




GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspCalculateSalary
     @monGrossSalary    AS MONEY  OUTPUT
    ,@monSalary         AS MONEY 
    ,@intFrequency      AS INTEGER
AS

SET XACT_ABORT ON   -- Terminate and rollback entire transaction on error

BEGIN

    SET @monGrossSalary = @monSalary / @intFrequency

END

GO


CREATE PROCEDURE uspCalculateGrossPay
     @monGrossPay       AS MONEY  OUTPUT
    ,@decHours          AS DECIMAL(6, 2) 
    ,@decRate           AS DECIMAL(6, 2)
AS

SET XACT_ABORT ON   -- Terminate and rollback entire transaction on error

BEGIN

    IF @decHours > 40
        SET @monGrossPay =  ((@decHours - 40) * @decRate * 1.5) + (40 * @decRate)
    ELSE
        SET @monGrossPay = @decHours * @decRate



END



GO


CREATE PROCEDURE uspCalculateTaxes
     @monFederalTax     AS MONEY  OUTPUT
    ,@monStateTax       AS MONEY  OUTPUT
    ,@monLocalTax       AS MONEY  OUTPUT
    ,@monGrossPay       AS MONEY  
    ,@decStateRate      AS DECIMAL(6,2)
    ,@decLocalRate      AS DECIMAL(6,2)

AS

SET XACT_ABORT ON   -- Terminate and rollback entire transaction on error


BEGIN



    SET @monStateTax = @monGrossPay * @decStateRate

    SET @monLocalTax = @monGrossPay * @decLocalRate


    IF @monGrossPay < 961.54 
        SET @monFederalTax = @monGrossPay * .07

    ELSE IF @monGrossPay > 961.54 and @monGrossPay < 1923.08
        SET @monFederalTax = @monGrossPay * .08

    Else If @monGrossPay > 1923.08 
        SET @monFederalTax = @monGrossPay * .09



END


GO


CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetGrossPay
         @monGrossPay       AS MONEY  OUTPUT
        ,@intEmployeeID     AS INTEGER

AS

SET XACT_ABORT ON   -- Terminate and rollback entire transaction on error

BEGIN

    DECLARE @monSalary          AS MONEY
    DECLARE @intPayrollStatusID AS INT  
    DECLARE @intFrequency       AS INTEGER
    DECLARE @decHours           AS DECIMAL(10, 2)
    DECLARE @monRate            AS MONEY
    DECLARE @monFederalTax      AS MONEY  
    DECLARE @monStateTax        AS MONEY  
    DECLARE @monLocalTax        AS MONEY  
    DECLARE @decFederalRate    AS DECIMAL(10,2)
    DECLARE @decStateRate       AS DECIMAL(10,2)
    DECLARE @decLocalRate       AS DECIMAL(10,2)

    DECLARE PayStatus CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT intPayrollStatusID FROM TEmployees
    WHERE intEmployeeID = @intEmployeeID    

    OPEN PayStatus

    FETCH FROM PayStatus
    INTO @intPayrollStatusID    

    Close PayStatus



    DECLARE GetTaxRate CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT decStateRate, decLocalRate FROM TTaxRates
    WHERE intEmployeeID = intEmployeeID



    DECLARE Salary CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT monSalary, intFrequency FROM TSalaries
    WHERE intEmployeeID = @intEmployeeID

    DECLARE Hourly CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT TER.monRate, TH.decHours FROM THourlyPayRate AS TER, THours AS TH
    WHERE TER.intEmployeeID = TH.intEmployeeID
    AND TH.intHourID IN (SELECT MAX(intHourID) FROM THours WHERE intEmployeeID = @intEmployeeID)


    IF @intPayrollStatusID = 1
        BEGIN
        --call Salery
            OPEN Salary

            FETCH FROM Salary
            INTO @monSalary, @intFrequency      

            CLOSE Salary

            EXECUTE uspCalculateSalary @monGrossPay OUTPUT, @monSalary, @intFrequency
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN

            OPEN Hourly

            FETCH Hourly
            INTO @monRate, @decHours

            CLOSE Hourly
            --call stored proc to calculate hourly pay
            EXECUTE uspCalculateGrossPay @monGrossPay OUTPUT, @decHours, @monRate
        END

            BEGIN

            OPEN GetTaxRate

            FETCH GetTaxRate
            INTO  @monGrossPay, @decStateRate, @decLocalRate

            CLOSE GetTaxRate
            --call stored proc to calculate hourly pay
            EXECUTE uspCalculateTaxes @monFederalTax OUTPUT, @monGrossPay,  @decStateRate, @decLocalRate

        END

    END
Go


DECLARE @monFederalTax AS MONEY
EXECUTE uspGetGrossPay @monFederalTax OUTPUT, 1
Print 'Federal Tax = ' + CAST(@monFederalTax as VARCHAR(50))


--DECLARE @monGross AS MONEY
--EXECUTE uspGetGrossPay @monGross OUTPUT, 2
--Print 'Gross Pay = ' + CAST(@monGross as VARCHAR(50))
```

Comment: Too much info here. Just show us the declaration of  `uspCalculateTaxes` nothing more

Comment: And what you have now to call `uspCalculateTaxes`

Comment: Your cursor logic is broken. You open the cursor to get a single value and then close it. That means you either have failed to iterate the rows or you are using a cursor when a single select statement would be sufficient. Additionally you should start using ANSI-92 style joins...they have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @nathan-knight You did not provide too much information. This was perfect to help me troubleshoot and correct the issues with uspGetGrossPay. I didn't have to waste time wondering about DML or creating my own test data.

Answer (score 0):

Everything except the definition of `uspGetGrossPay` seems good. But `uspGetGrossPay` needs some changes. First, you don't need cursors here. Using `SELECT TOP 1` along with variable assignments will work better for getting single scalar values. After we get rid of the unnecessary and incorrect cursor definitions, we just have to add a couple OUTPUT parameters into the call to `uspCalculateTaxes`, clean up some orphaned `BEGIN...END` blocks, and Bob's your uncle, as they say.

Your updated `uspGetGrossPay` would then look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetGrossPay
    @monGrossPay AS MONEY OUTPUT
    ,@intEmployeeID AS INTEGER
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON -- Terminate and rollback entire transaction on error

BEGIN
    DECLARE @monSalary AS MONEY
    DECLARE @intPayrollStatusID AS INT
    DECLARE @intFrequency AS INTEGER
    DECLARE @decHours AS DECIMAL(10, 2)
    DECLARE @monRate AS MONEY
    DECLARE @monFederalTax AS MONEY
    DECLARE @monStateTax AS MONEY
    DECLARE @monLocalTax AS MONEY
    DECLARE @decFederalRate AS DECIMAL(10, 2)
    DECLARE @decStateRate AS DECIMAL(10, 2)
    DECLARE @decLocalRate AS DECIMAL(10, 2)

    SELECT @intPayrollStatusID = intPayrollStatusID
    FROM TEmployees
    WHERE intEmployeeID = @intEmployeeID

    SELECT TOP 1
        @decStateRate  = decStateRate
        ,@decLocalRate = decLocalRate
    FROM TTaxRates
    WHERE intEmployeeID = @intEmployeeID

    SELECT TOP 1
        @monSalary     = monSalary
        ,@intFrequency = intFrequency
    FROM TSalaries
    WHERE intEmployeeID = @intEmployeeID

    SELECT TOP 1
        @monRate   = TER.monRate
        ,@decHours = TH.decHours
    FROM THourlyPayRate TER
    INNER JOIN THours   TH ON TER.intEmployeeID = TH.intEmployeeID
                               AND TH.intHourID IN (
                                                       SELECT MAX(intHourID)
                                                       FROM THours
                                                       WHERE intEmployeeID = @intEmployeeID
                                                   )

    IF @intPayrollStatusID = 1
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE uspCalculateSalary @monGrossPay OUTPUT, @monSalary, @intFrequency
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE uspCalculateGrossPay @monGrossPay OUTPUT, @decHours, @monRate
    END

    EXECUTE uspCalculateTaxes
        @monFederalTax OUTPUT
        ,@monStateTax OUTPUT
        ,@monLocalTax OUTPUT
        ,@monGrossPay
        ,@decStateRate
        ,@decLocalRate
END
GO
```

Running this for your test data gave me the following result: `Federal Tax = 1730.77`